# Программа выводит Unexpected EOF во время выполнения

Tags: c++, отладка, олимпиада

Я решаю одну задачу на С++.
Вот её код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
vector<int> decomp (int n)
{
    vector<int> ans (0);
    int d = 2;
    while (d * d <= n)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
        {
            ans.push_back(d);
            n /= d;
        }
        else
            d += 1;
    }
    if (n > 1)
        ans.push_back(n);
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int x; cin >> x;
    if (x == 1)
        cout << 1;
    else
    {
        vector<int> tmp = decomp(x);
        unordered_set<int> s;
        for (int el: tmp)
            s.insert(el);
        vector<int> a (0);
        for (int el: s)
            a.push_back(el);
        int y = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            y *= a[i];
        if (y >= 29)
            cout << y;
        else
        {
            int n;
            for (int k = 1; k <= 29; k++)
            {
                n = k * y;
                if ((int)pow(n, n) % x == 0)
                {
                    cout << n;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Тестировщик на одном из тестов выдаёт следующее сообщение: "user program output: Unexpected EOF"
Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и из-за чего она возникает? (тестовые данные мне не известны...)
Вот текст задачи:

> Для того чтобы проверить, как её ученики умеют считать, Мария Ивановна каждый год задаёт им на дом одну и ту же задачу — для заданного натурального A найти минимальное натуральное N такое, что N в степени N (N, умноженное на себя N раз) делится на A. вам необходимо написать программу, решающую эту задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на вашу ветвь else — что будет, если `y < 29`, но условие `((int)pow(n, n) % x == 0)` так ни разу и не будет выполнено? никакое значение выведено не будет. Программа завершится без вывода.

Тестирующая программа обнаружит, что канал вывода закрылся, а ответ так и не получен. Произошел неожиданный конец вывода данных — так как ожидалось число. Вот и сообщение отсюда.

Почему такое может произойти — это уже другой вопрос: как написать правильное решение поставленной задачи :)

P.S. Совет на будущее: когда задаете "олимпиадные" задачи, давайте URL проверяющей системы, чтоб не бегать и не искать [ссылку](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=19946&chapterid=1009#1)...

Comment: На будущее понял. Вот только я решаю задачи на edu.sirius.online, и там надо логиниться на сам курс, чтобы получить доступ ко всему. Буду искать в других местах )